# Каким образом в Android Studio проект пометить как библиотека

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Сегодня решил перейти на Android Studio с Eclips-а. Все вроде бы получилось. Но столкнулся с непониманием. У меня есть некий проект. В Ecplipse я в его свойствах ставил галочку isLibrary и мог использовать его в других проектах. Это удобно было. Исправив проект, его изменения касались всех других проектов к которым он подключен. В AS я добавил его через Project Structure как модуль и для приложения указал его как dependencies. Потом решил поправить проект-библиотеку, но эти изменения никак не отразились в проекте где я ее как бы подключил. Как мне сделать, что бы логика осталась как была раньше в Eclipse. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать ребилд проекта основного после внесение изменений в проекте-библиотеке?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, наверное нет. Сейчас попробую. Просто никак не могу привыкнуть к тому, что AS постоянно нужно о чем то просить, тогда как Ecplipse сразу шустренько искал ошибки. А тут это мучительно...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ребилд сделал, ничего не поменялось, к сожалению.

Comment: Вообще, по сравнению с `Ecplipse` в `AS` всё лучше) Надо просто привыкнуть. А по сути проблемы... Ну... Приложите, что ли, `build.gradle` к вопросу. Возможно, вы в нём как-то не так подключили библиотеку вашу...

Comment: в build.gradle проекта в разделе dependencies написано `compile project(':mylib')`, а в Settings.gradle `include ':app', ':jsoup-1.8.3', ':mylib'`

Comment: Почитал дублирующую ссылку. Попробовал, но ничего не получилось. По ссылке написал комментарий, что не так. Помогите пожалуйста.